# How to print networking device output in Html using python flask

Tags: python, flask, networking, device

TThe following is the output of device

PASSCODE Accepted

acr01.aurora.co# show version

Chassis Type: E6000

Slot Description       HW Version          Software Version        Uptime

0    UCAM-2 Spare      UCAM-22431W/C10     CER_V06.04.00.0026      21 days  3:49:52

1    UCAM-2            UCAM-22431W/C10     CER_V06.04.00.0026      21 days  4:24:35

2    UCAM-2            UCAM-22431W/C10     CER_V06.04.00.0026      21 days  4:10:38

3    UCAM-2            UCAM-22431W/C10     CER_V06.04.00.0026      21 days  3:54:56

4    DCAM-B            DCAM-08256W/D14     CER_V06.04.00.0026      21 days  4:24:37

5    DCAM-B            DCAM-08256W/D05     CER_V06.04.00.0026      21 days  4:10:40

6    RSM A             RSM-08241W/D03      CER_V06.04.00.0026      21 days  4:33:32

7    RSM B             RSM-08241W/D08      CER_V06.04.00.0026      21 days  3:15:42

8    DCAM-B            DCAM-08256W/D08     CER_V06.04.00.0026      21 days  3:54:58

9    DCAM-B            DCAM-08256W/D05     CER_V06.04.00.0026      21 days  3:41:26

10   DCAM-B            DCAM-08256W/D05     CER_V06.04.00.0026      21 days  3:36:09

11   DCAM-B            DCAM-08256W/D05     CER_V06.04.00.0026      21 days  3:30:52

12   DCAM-B            DCAM-08256W/D05     CER_V06.04.00.0026      21 days  3:25:35

13   DCAM-B Spare      DCAM-08256W/D05     CER_V06.04.00.0026      21 days  3:23:38

acr01.aurora.co# exit 
My code is

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
import telnetlib
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():


    HOST = 'acr01.aurora.co.denver.comcast.net'
    user = 'username'+"\n"
    password = 'password'+"\n"


    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST,23,50)
    tn.set_debuglevel(1)
    tn.read_until(b'Username: ')
    tn.write(user.encode('ascii'))
    tn.read_until(b'Enter PASSCODE: ')
    tn.write(password.encode('ascii'))
    #tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)


    #cmd='show version'+"\n"
    tn.write(b'show version'+b"\n")
    #t1=(tn.read_eager())
    #print(t1)
    #cmd1='exit' + "\n"
    tn.write(b'exit'+b"\n")
    #t2=tn.read_eager()
    #print(t2)

    """while True:
        line = tn.read_until(b"\n")  # Read one line
        print(line)"""


    output=tn.read_all()
    """for row in output:
        print(row)
        tn.read_until(b"\n")"""
    return render_template("home.html",output=output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

home.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Add book</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="/">



    <h1>Books</h1>
    <table>
      {% for book in output %}
        <tr>
          <td>
            {{book[0]}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{book[1]}}
            {{book[1]}}
            {{book[2]}}
            {{book[3]}}
            {{book[4]}}
          </td>

        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```